# How to model the additive components of a random variable whose value is known

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-regression, compositional-data, constraint

I would like to model the variables $Y_1, Y_2, …, Y_n$, which satisfy the constraint $Y_1 + Y_2 + … + Y_n = Y$; where $Y$ (or at least an accurate estimate $\hat{Y}$ thereof) is readily available. More specifically, I am interested in the relative proportions of $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$. I have some other explanatory variables that I plan to use for this modelling and a very large dataset.

My current idea is:

- Model $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ as a multivariate vector, including $\hat{Y}$ as one of the predictor variables in $X$
- Add a post-processing step which normalises $Y_i$ to sum to 1
- Choose a loss function based on these relative proportions

It seems good enough, especially since we have a large amount of labelled data. However, I am wondering if there is a model which lends itself to this specific problem more naturally.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: Hi: There is something called "hierarchical forecasting". It doesn't exactly apply to your case but there may be modifications or variants that do ? I would google and check it out.

Comment: This sounds like compositional analysis, maybe add the tag [tag:compositional-data].